# SQLITE db files not closed. db-shm and db-wal files remain

Tags: python, sqlite

I want to write some basic code to do querys on read only mode on sqlite databases

These are daily db files so it is important after closing the connections not to leave other files in the server like *db-shm* or *db-wal* files associated

I have been reading the documentation and it seems that even though I try to close the connections explicitly, these are not closed so these files stay there

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd


def _connect(f):
    
    con = None
    try:
        con = sqlite3.connect("file:"+f+"?mode=ro", uri=True)
       

    except sqlite3.Error as er:
        print('SQLite error in the db connection: %s' % (' '.join(er.args)))
    return con  
    
def _disconnect(con):
    
    try:
        con.close()
        
    except sqlite3.Error as er:
        print('SQLite error in the db disconnection: %s' % (' '.join(er.args)))
    return con  

def fl_query(file):
    
    '''Returns information about a db file
    
        file : string
                absolute path to the db file
        returns
        -------
            list
    '''
    
    cn = _connect(file)  
    cur = cn.cursor()        

    query = """SELECT ....etc"""  
    cur.execute(query)           
  
    
    info = [(row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3],row[4],row[5]) for row in cur.fetchall()]
    
    cur.close()
    _disconnect(cn)

    return info



folder = 'path to the db file'
file = folder+'6100000_2022-09-18.db'    
info = fl_query(file)
```

I have read about how to close cleanly the databases but so far nothing works and db-shm and db-wal stay there everytime I open a file. Remark: it is a server with thousand of files so it is important not to create more files

[image]

Comment: Thousand? I have several hundred thousand on my laptop. You should not mess with journal files. You can clean up old files periodically.

Comment: I repeat, leaving these files there is not an option. These files are supposed to dissapear once the connection is closed and they are not. So that is the question, is there something missing in my code? Why these files stay there?

Comment: Because these files are used to ensure ACIDity. If you do not care about ACIDity, disable journaling. If you need ACIDity, then you will NOT be able to delete them right away. This whole notion is weird. Temporary files ARE ABSOLUTELY necessary for correct functioning of certain processes. Under no circumstances can you disable creation of temporary files or control their lifetime without crippling your system. I bet if you search your server, you will find a bunch of files in the temp folder at any given time, as well as other instances of SQLite with journal files.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I was unable to modify the PRAGMA Journal because I was opening the database in read only mode. In read-write mode it performs the modification of the PRAGMA journal to DELETE mode

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd


def _connect(f):
    
    con = None
    try:
        con = sqlite3.connect("file:"+f+"?mode=rw", uri=True)
       

    except sqlite3.Error as er:
        print('SQLite error in the db connection: %s' % (' '.join(er.args)))
    return con  
    
def _disconnect(con):
    
    try:
        con.close()
        
    except sqlite3.Error as er:
        print('SQLite error in the db disconnection: %s' % (' '.join(er.args)))
    return con  

def fl_query(file):
    
    '''Returns information about a db file
    
        file : string
                absolute path to the db file
        returns
        -------
            list
    '''
    
    cn = _connect(file)  
    cur = cn.cursor()        
    cur.execute("PRAGMA journal_mode=DELETE")
    query = """SELECT ....etc"""  
    cur.execute(query)           
  
    
    info = [(row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3],row[4],row[5]) for row in cur.fetchall()]
    
    cur.close()
    _disconnect(cn)
```